# Executing a Command from C# and Wait to Finish executing

Tags: c#, cmd, iis-6

I have a program that will create a new website in IIS 6.
How do I make my the execution of commands wait until it finishes.
Currently it doesn't wait, so the website doesn't get created.

I cannot use a .bat file because the **DirectoryPath**, **SiteName**, **AppPoolName**, and **PortNumber** are provided by using while running the application.

The below code is executed on a background thread and not the main thread.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = Environment.SystemDirectory + "/cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"cd %systemroot%\system32" + " & " + @"cscript iisweb.vbs /create " + DirectoryPath + " " + SiteName + " /ap " + AppPoolName + " /b " + PortNumber + " & " + "exit";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: WaitForExit? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx

Comment: I have the WaitForExit. But it's not working. Does it have to do something with background thread?

Answer (score 4):

I figured out what the problem was.

```
startInfo.Arguments = @"cd %systemroot%\system32" + " & " + @"cscript iisweb.vbs /create " + DirectoryPath + " " + SiteName + " /ap " + AppPoolName + " /b " + PortNumber + " & " + "exit";
```

I added `/C` at the beginning of the startInfo.Arguments and it worked just fine.

Here is the answer that worked.

```
 startInfo.Arguments = @"/C cd %systemroot%\system32" + " & " + @"cscript iisweb.vbs /create " + DirectoryPath + " " + SiteName + " /ap " + AppPoolName + " /b " + PortNumber + " & " + "exit";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you wanna run your commands on the main thread? If so, don't you wanna wait till the background thread finishes?